# List push back method not being called for own struct

Tags: c++

I've been trying to play around for a bit and I want to rewrite a bit of code to be more understandable for a faculty student.

This is the initial code:

```
typedef pair<int, int> iPair; 

// un graf directionat cu reprezentare prin lista de adiacenta
class Graph 
{ 
    int V; // Numar de noduri

    // Lista care retine nodul si costul muchiei pentru fiecare pereche
    list< pair<int, int> > *adj; 

public: 
    Graph(int V); // constructorul

    // adauga o muchie grafului
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w); 

    // printeaza mst-ul rezultat
    void primMST(int numberElemOp); 
}; 

// aloca memorie pentru lista de adiacenta
Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new list<iPair> [V]; 
} 

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w)); 
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w)); 
}
```

Atm I would like to have a custom Pair made by me:

```
    # define INF 0x3f3f3f3f 

// pereche int int denumita iPair
struct Pair {
    int first;
    int second;
}; 

struct Pair* newPair(int first, int second){
    struct Pair* newPair = (struct Pair*)malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
    newPair->first = first;
    newPair->second = second;

    return newPair;
}

// un graf directionat cu reprezentare prin lista de adiacenta
class Graph 
{ 
    int V; // Numar de noduri

    // Lista care retine nodul si costul muchiei pentru fiecare pereche
    list< Pair > *adj; 

public: 
    Graph(int V) {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<Pair> [V]; 
    }; // constructorul

    // adauga o muchie grafului
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w){
        adj[u].push_back(newPair(v, w)); // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/ pentru push back
        adj[v].push_back(newPair(u, w)); 
    };
```

I think I respect the types and all but I can't quite figure out this error:

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'void Graph::addEdge(int, int, int)':
prog.cpp:35:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::list<Pair>::push_back(Pair*)'
   adj[u].push_back(newPair(v, w));
```

In my mind i give my custom Pair to the list and it should be pushed to the list. What's the issue?

Comment: Currently, you are trying to push a `Pair*` (pointer to dynamically allocated `Pair` object in your case), into a list of `Pair`, which is why the code fails.

Comment: hmmm, should i make the list a list of pointers maybe ?

Comment: @LucianTarna Why hampering with pointers at all? Just use the values.

Comment: You should avoid (manual) dynamic allocation as much as possible. There is no need to allocate the `Pair` object dynamically here, and there is no need to allocate the array of `std::list` manually (`std::vector` does this for you). In modern C++, a `new` keyword (or worse, a `malloc`) in your code is usually a red-flag.

Comment: In you use at least C++ 11, you could also use `emplace` instead of `push_back`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error you are getting is because:

```
struct Pair* newPair(int first, int second);
```

...returns a pointer to a `Pair` object (`Pair*`), so when you do:

```
adj[v].push_back(newPair(u, w));
```

...you are trying to push a `Pair*` where a simple `Pair` is expected.

The simple fix here is to not allocate your `Pair` object dynamically:

```
// You don't need to prefix "Pair" with "struct" in C++:
Pair newPair(int first, int second) {
    return { first, second };
}
```

---

Your code has some other flaws, some of which are pretty "dangerous". You should not allocate an array of `std::list` manually, this is error prone (you need to take care of copying your `Graph` structure and freeing the memory), simply use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::list<Pair>> adj;

// No needs to store the value of V since you can retrieve it with adj.size()
Graph(int V) : adj(V) { }
```

Furthermore, `std::list` are usually a bad idea. You should rather use `std::vector`s:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Pair>> adj;

Graph(int V) : adj(V) { }
```

---

A "better" version of your `Graph` would be:

```
struct Edge {
    const int destination;
    const int weight;
};

class Graph {
     // Adjacency list:
     std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> adj;

public:

    Graph(int V) : adj(V) { }

    void addEdge(int from, int to, int weight) {
        adj[from].push_back({to, weight});
        adj[to].push_back({from, weight});
    }

};
```

Comment: `std::make_pair` can also be used instead of your own `newPair` function that does similar thing.

Comment: @Phil1970 `std::make_pair` creates a `std::pair`, OP wants to use its own `Pair` type (not `iPair` as in the first example).